# How to save a bitmap image with imageview onclick

Tags: android, android-gallery

Am developing a coloring of images in android. So after applying colors to my image when i click another imageview like save, then i have to save that image to gallery.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To get Bitmap from `imageView`:

```
imageview.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm=imageview.getDrawingCache();
```

To save it in a file:

```
OutputStream fOut = null;
Uri outputFileUri;
try {
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + File.separator + "folder_name" + File.separator);
    root.mkdirs();
    File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "myPicName.jpg");
    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
    fOut = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured. Please try again later.",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
try {
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
    fOut.flush();
    fOut.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks let me try this.... @Seshu Vinay

Comment: Hey vinay i getting error msg "Error occured. Please try again later." even am unable to see any directory created in root directory??

Comment: add permission in manifest:<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: After adding this line to manifest file also im getting the same error vinay???

Comment: I dint see anything in logcat, but on emulator am able to see the catch stmt error "Error occured. Please try again later". Even i put prints for file root,sdImageMainDirectory and able to see path in logcat. But when i adb to emulator i dint see any folder name tat i have created in /mnt/sdcard/ path..

Comment: This is the value " Value of e =java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Photos (Is a directory) "

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7230/discussion-between-andriod-murali-and-seshu-vinay)

Comment: Hey vinay now am able to see created directory in emulator terminal(/mnt/sdcard) but unable to view image in it??

Comment: Hey vinay its working for me thanks a tone dude....

Comment: @SeshuVinay useful answer, but can you please tell why have you taken outputFileUri variable and assigned that value, because you haven't used it

Comment: @WhyandHow I copied this code snippet from one of my programs. I forgot to delete that line. It's useful somewhere in my program

Answer (score 3):

You have to

1. Save the image to your persistent storage.
2. Add an entry to the [MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) content provider.

First one can be achieved using the following code:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
```

Second,

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, imagePath, name, description);
```

Comment: Thanks let me try this.... @Ragunath Jawahar

Answer (score -1):

First get the drawingCache(bitmap) of the imageView and then save the bitmap to the SDCard.

File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/folder/");
    if(!folder.exists()) folderAppointment.mkdirs();

```
try {
    this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/folder/file"));
    Bitmap bitmap = YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW.getDrawingCache();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks let me try this.... @akkilis