# Store the taken picture from ImageView to the phone storage

Tags: java, android

After I take a picture I store the picture into ImageView, So if anyone has an idea or suggestion in how to store the picture after it shown on the ImageView into phone stage without user interaction
Thanks in advance

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView viewpict;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewpict=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pict_result);
        Button btn= (Button)findViewById(R.id.camera);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            //  Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),MainActivity2.class);

                //startActivity(intent);
                startActivityForResult(intent,0);

            }

     });


    }

protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode==0)
    {
        Bitmap theimage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        viewpict.setImageBitmap(theimage);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078715/how-to-save-a-bitmap-image-with-imageview-onclick

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
viewpict.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm=viewpict.getDrawingCache();
```

And save:

```
 OutputStream fOut = null;
    Uri outputFileUri;
     try {
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
      + File.separator + "folder_name" + File.separator);
    root.mkdirs();
   File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "myPicName.jpg");
    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
    fOut = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory);
   } catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured. Please try again later.",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   try {
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
    fOut.flush();
    fOut.close();
   } catch (Exception e) {
   }
```

And permission in AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```