# how to download the image in the list view on click without web url?

Tags: java, android

[image: **enter image description here**]

how to make users to download the image in the listview  onclick of the list item.The images are from drawable folder, not from the web?

Comment: do you want to save images from drawable folder?

Comment: save images in drawable folder and add into integer arraylist and use it on click of list item.

Comment: please be specific about what you ask. what does this statement mean?  "The images are from drawable folder, not from the web?"  are you telling it or asking it?

Comment: The images which i shown in the list are from the drawable folder.now, when an end user clicks any of the list item the image in the item should get download.

Comment: If your images are already in the drawable folder, then they are already installed with your app. **Download** is when you get things from the internet. You are probably saying **display** the image when the user click the item is the `listView`. If that is the case, check my answer.

Answer (score 4):

**if you are referring to saving images to your phone, from your drawable folder.you should check this link out.**
**[How to save a bitmap image with imageview onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078715/how-to-save-a-bitmap-image-with-imageview-onclick)**

**it says how to save an image from the app to your phone**

To get bitmap from imageview:

```
imageview.buildDrawingCache();   
Bitmap bm=imageview.getDrawingCache();
```

To save it in a file:

```
OutputStream fOut = null;
Uri outputFileUri;
try {
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "folder_name" + File.separator);
    root.mkdirs();
    File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "myPicName.jpg");
    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
    fOut = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured. Please try again later.",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

try {
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
    fOut.flush();

    fOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

give this inside the listview on click

Answer (score 0):

You can store your images id in an `int[]` integer array like this:

```
int[] myImages = {R.drawable.myfirstimage,R.drawable.mysecondimage};
```

and add to your `listView` an `onItemClick` method where you change your corresponding `ImageView` based on the position of the item clicked

```
myListview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(myImages[position]);
        }
    });
```