# Saving the Image with It's source Name?

Tags: android, delphi, android-glide, android-storage

I want to save the image which was loaded in `ImageView` using `Glide` with it's source or original name in folder named MyData. I have no idea how can I do this.

**THIS IS THE CODE I USED IN DELPHI TO SAVE THE IMAGE**

```
  if FileExists(Path) then
     begin
       IDHTTP1.Get(URL,MS);
       MS.Seek(0,soBeginning);
       Image1.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(MS);
       if not TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXPhotoLibrary, Gallery) then
        Exit;
       Gallery.AddImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(Image1.Bitmap);
     end;
```

Comment: you need to get bitmap from imageview and save it to sdcard follow the given link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078715/how-to-save-a-bitmap-image-with-imageview-onclick

Comment: @Adeel sir but what about the Source Or original file name ? Please answer.

Comment: well the file name must be in the url you are passing to glide

Comment: Nope I can only send the request for the image. The URL is only known to server which is being owned by Facebook.

Comment: hmm then its not possible .. why do you want the same filename :? cant think of any use case

Comment: Well I had done this using Pascal/Delphi I'll post the code. Please wait.

Comment: gud .. have a happy coding .. it seems like you wanted to answer yourself :P  J.K its gud to share knowledge in SO..

Comment: Wait I think the URL has the image name but how can I use that name automatically while saving the image ?

Comment: split url string using / you will get a string array in the last iondex you will have thge image name.. boom

Comment: The server's HTTP response likely contains the filename. Look to see if there is a `Content-Disposition` response header with a `filename` attribute, or a `Content-Type` response header with a `name` attribute.  If not, then you need to parse the URL and extract a filename from the end of the resource path. You can use Indy's `TIdURI` to help you with that parsing.

Comment: Be aware that web images are not always served from web servers as files but also as image streams. This is especially popular on web pages with dynamic content. So in such case you actually wont have any image file name available.